# Запуск файла PHP с помощью команды крон

Tags: cron, php

Уважаемые, прошу помощи, не нашёл в гугле ни чего интересующего.
В общем, задача такая, у меня ВДС (VDS) нужно, чтобы крон запускал файл php на сайте.
Панель IPSManager, настройки понятны, но не знаю какую команду прописать, чтобы он запускал, к примеру, *sait.ru/123.php*.
С кроном ни когда не работал, по этому обращаюсь к Вам.

Система *debian-5.0-i386*.

Буду даже благодарен мануалу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для начала от root'а:

```
# crontab -e
```

И прописываешь правило:

```
*/1 *  * * *    /usr/bin/php-cgi /home/html/site.ru/123.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Сохраняем. Это правило будет запускать скрипт каждую минуту. А далее читаем man cron, там все предельно понятно написано. Должен быть установлен php5-cli.

Comment: а зачем от рута то ?

Comment: > ... /usr/bin/php-cgi ...
>
> Должен быть установлен php5-cli.

А зачем тогда через cgi запускать-то?

Answer (score 3):

Главное решить из под какого пользователя нужно запускать этот скрипт, из под того-же что и сайт работает или из под какого-то другого.

Если пользователь выбран, если это псевдо-user типа www-data, то поставить скрипт из под root-а:

```
# crontab -u www-data -e
или
# crontab -e www-data file
```

если из под текущего пользователя то:

```
$ crontab -e
или
$ crontab file
```

Собственно формат файла описан в `crontab`, см `man 5 crontab`

**А из под root-а я-бы настоятельно не рекомендовал запускать php-скрипты**